# Dropzone laravel No data found for resource with given identifier when upload code in server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

this is function code store
upload small file accept but size from 15 mega this message appear
in local this issue not appear only appear in server

```
public function storeMedia(Request $request)
    {
        $path = storage_path('tmp/uploads');
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 777, true);
        }
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $name = uniqid() . '_' . trim($file->getClientOriginalName());
        $file->move($path, $name);
        return response()->json([
            'name'          => $name,
            'original_name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        ]);
    }
```

this is blade code

```
<script>
            var uploadedDocumentMap = {}
            Dropzone.options.documentDropzone = {
                url: "{{ route('sheets.storeMedia') }}",
                maxFilesize: 100, // MB
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                },
                success: function(file, response) {
                    $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="file[]" value="' + response.name + '">')
                    uploadedDocumentMap[file.name] = response.name
                    var uploadedFiles = response.files;
                },
                removedfile: function(file) {
                    file.previewElement.remove()
                    var name = ''
                    if (typeof file.file_name !== 'undefined') {
                        name = file.file_name
                    } else {
                        name = uploadedDocumentMap[file.name]
                    }
                    $('form').find('input[name="file[]"][value="' + name + '"]').remove()
                },
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: can you post the actual error message? Do not use image for this.